# Will batch script wait while it is executing NET STOP?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a batch script which runs on a server and stops a service. 
Sometimes there is an issue whereby the service is unable stop using NET STOP and the service needs to be killed. 
To get around this I added an IF statement to Kill the service if not stopped.

```
NET STOP "Service"

FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H IN ('sc query "Service" ^| findstr "        STATE"') DO (
  IF /I "%%H" EQU "RUNNING" (
   :: Kill the service if it is still running
   Taskkill /F /FI "SERVICES eq Service"
  )
)
```

I have tried to search this but cannot see a definitive answer.

The question is; Is the kill process being run only after the 'NET STOP' has completed, or does it start trying to stop the service and immediately run IF Statement.

If the later I will need to add a timeout.exe line in between to give the NET STOP enough time to do its thing.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I believe the answer is yes NET STOP will wait. SC wont and will tend to return a Pending state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NET STOP` is synchronous. This means that script will wait for it to finish. Further you don't even need to check the service with `SC`. `NET STOP` has the following return codes:

- 0 = Success
- 1 = Not Supported
- 2 = Access Denied
- 3 = Dependent Services Running
- 4 = Invalid Service Control
- 5 = Service Cannot Accept Control
- 6 = Service Not Active
- 7 = Service Request Timeout
- 8 = Unknown Failure
- 9 = Path Not Found
- 10 = Service Already Running
- 11 = Service Database Locked
- 12 = Service Dependency Deleted
- 13 = Service Dependency Failure
- 14 = Service Disabled
- 15 = Service Logon Failure
- 16 = Service Marked For Deletion
- 17 = Service No Thread
- 18 = Status Circular Dependency
- 19 = Status Duplicate Name
- 20 = Status Invalid Name
- 21 = Status Invalid Parameter
- 22 = Status Invalid Service Account
- 23 = Status Service Exists
- 24 = Service Already Paused

So you can just check if the return code is 0 (`%ERRORLEVEL%==0` - means the service was stopped) and kill it otherwise.

Comment: Where is the docs? In most case, it return 2, including the service already stop.